# Python REST API Calls Structuring

Tags: python, api, rest

I am writing a python REST API library for Starburst and am trying to figure out the best way to structure the code so it's dry but also easy to understand. This is what I have so far.

```python
class StarburstAPI(object):

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, oauth=None, session=None):

        self.api_version = 'v1'
        self.base_url = 'https://starburst.com/api/' + self.api_version

        self.headers = default_headers()
        self.params = {}

        if session is None:
            session = requests.Session()
        self._session = session

        if username is not None or password is not None:
            self._session.auth = (username, password)

        self._session.cookies = self._session.head(self.base_url).cookies
        self._session.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    
    # Get list of domains
    def list_domains(self):

        url = self.base_url + '/dataProduct/domains/'

        return self._session.get(url)
    

    # Get domain by id
    def get_domain(self, id: str):

        url = self.base_url + '/dataProduct/domains/' + id

        return self._session.get(url)
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). SO is for questions about non-working code, rather than improvements to working code.

Comment: Noted, thanks! I'll move my inquiry over there.